# How can I pass a command line argument to the graphical debugger in CS50 ide?

Tags: linux, debugging, cs50

So I can run the debugger by right clicking the program tab and choosing 'run this file', but I don't see an option to enter any command line arguments, and i get the following;
[image]

i tried entering fifteen 3 where the 3 currently sits and the same happened.

Answer (score 0):

On the top of the terminal where it currently says 'Command' and then 'pset3/fifteen/fifteen.c' -- that's where you need to add your command line argument.  It should work once you hit 'run' again.  Another issue I run into with the GDB is already having an instance of it running causing it to hang.  Make sure you kill any instances of it by running 'ps aux' and noting the PID of any GDB instances and then running 'kill -9 [PID]' -- hope this helps!

Comment: @roncook does that help? If so, please mark answer correct. Thanks!